# grep exact string variable

Tags: grep

I want to grep  the exact string 'CAAJ' from a file "aaa.log" and it following contents.

```
cat aaa.log

CAAJ:dd20gf:acldx009:rel7

CAAJ:dd20gi:acldx009:rel7

CAAJ:dd20gp:acldx0059:rel7

CAAJ-TEST:de27ff:acldx003:rel7

CAAJ-TEST:de27ei:acldx003:rel7

CAAJ-TEST:de27ep:acldx003:rel7
```

Expected Output:

```
CAAJ:dd20gf:acldx009:rel7

CAAJ:dd20gi:acldx009:rel7

CAAJ:dd20gp:acldx0059:rel7
```

I am trying the following code.And i get the O/p.

```
grep -E '(^|)CAAJ(:|$)' aaa.log

CAAJ:dd20gf:acldx009:rel7

CAAJ:dd20gi:acldx009:rel7

CAAJ:dd20gp:acldx0059:rel7
```

But when I use a Variable instead of the exact string I am unable to get the O/p

```
var=CAAJ

grep -E '(^|)${var}(:|$)' aaa.log

OR 

grep -E '(^|)"${var}"(:|$)' aaa.log
```

None of these worked.

I want to use the  variable instead of the exact string and get the desired o/p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var=CAAJ;grep "^$var:" aaa.log;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
awk -F: '$1=="CAAJ" aaa.log
```

using variable in awk

```
awk -F: -vv="$var" '$1==v' aaa.log
```

grep command

```
grep "^$var:" aaa.log
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I have no idea what you *think* the parentheses are doing, but there is no reason at all to use `(^|)`.  That means "start of the string, or nothing."  I'm surprised it's valid syntax.

Likewise, `(:|$)` seems senseless when all of the occurrences you care about occur at the *start* of the string.

If you put a variable in double quotes it will expand.  If you put it in single quotes it won't.

You don't need extended regex for any of this.

---

Instead of:

```
grep -E '(^|)'${var}'(:|$)'
```

Use:

```
grep ^CAAJ: aaa.log
```

Or:

```
var=CAAJ
grep "^${var}:" aaa.log
```

Or, since the field delimiter you care about is `:`, just use Awk:

```
awk -F: '$1 == "CAAJ"' aaa.log
```

Note that in this last case, the single quotes are for the shell and the double quotes are for Awk.  Everything inside of the single quotes, including `$1`, will be passed to Awk exactly as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with the ' and it worked.

```
grep -E '(^|)'${var}'(:|$)'
```

Answer (score -2):

try

```
grep -E "(^|)${var}(:|$)" aaa.log
```